# Microsoft Graph API returning 404 error missing parameter, despite grant_type in query string

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api

Calling the Microsoft Graph API to get an access token via part 4 of this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?view=graph-rest-1.0

I'm performing the following fetch request:

```
  var options = {
    "method": "POST",
    "contentType": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "accept": 'application/json',
    "headers": {
      'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    },
  }
  var authorization_url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenant + 
    "/oauth2/v2.0/token/" + 
      "client_id=" + client_id + 
        "&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default" +
          "&client_secret=" + client_secret + 
              "&grant_type=client_credentials";
```

Fairly confident that all my parameters are correct, but it returns an invalid request error: "The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'". Any idea what could be going wrong?

Comment: I don't know the API, but the error message refers to the *body* specifically, whereas you're putting a flag in the URI query section, not the request body.

Answer (score 2):

Your `authorization_url` should only include the endpoint (i.e. no query string):

```js
var authorization_url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenant + "/oauth2/v2.0/token/"
```

The parameters belong in the body of the `POST`:

```js
var payload = 
    "client_id=" + client_id + 
    "&client_secret=" + client_secret + 
    "&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default" +
    "&grant_type=client_credentials";
```

(your `options` looks fine to me)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you refer to the [token request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?view=graph-rest-1.0#token-request) section on [that page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?view=graph-rest-1.0).

It shows the following representation of an HTTP request:

```
// Line breaks are for legibility only.

POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=535fb089-9ff3-47b6-9bfb-4f1264799865
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default
&client_secret=qWgdYAmab0YSkuL1qKv5bPX
&grant_type=client_credentials
```

The lowest part represents the body of the HTTP request, not the arguments passed in the URL query string.

I suggest that you change your code to accomodate those changes.